# What are the http methods used in GIT smart http

Tags: git, smart-http

I am trying to configure git using a login servlet, so want to know what all http methods are used in smart http

Answer (score 2):

I believe only GET and POST requests are made. According to a blog post on Git's website concerning [smart HTTP transport](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/04/smart-http.html), it seems like that.

**EDIT**: Checked current Git's source code in master branch (3d092bfc) and discovered that http-backend.c accepts HEAD requests too. After detecting a HEAD request it immediately starts treating it as a GET. According to `services[]` and `main()` in the same source file, only GET and POST requests are handled otherwise.

Comment: Note that "smart" HTTP transport uses GET even for `git push` (as first step); this has different URI structure and has or had been trouble when configuring anonymous read + authenthicated write configuration.